# how to parse string for capitalized words

Tags: c#, regex

I have this string: `" Mimi loves Toto and Tata hate Mimi so Toto killed Tata"`

I want to write a code that print only the words that begin with capital letters, avoiding repetition

the Output should be like

```
Mimi
Toto
Tata
```

I tried to do so but I'm sure its wrong even though no errors are showing.

The code i wrote :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string s = "Memi ate Toto and she killed Tata Memi also hate Biso";
            Console.WriteLine((spliter(s)));
        }



        public static string spliter(string s)
        {

            string x = s;
            Regex exp = new Regex(@"[A-Z]");
            MatchCollection M = exp.Matches(s);

            foreach (Match t in M)
            {

                while (x != null)
                {
                    x = t.Value;  
                }

            }
            return x;
        }


    }
}
```

### Idea:

What if i split the string into an array, then apply a regex to check them word by word and then print the results ? I don't know - can any one help me in making this code work?

Comment: You want to print letters that start with capital case letters? I'm confused

Comment: I think he meant words that start with capital letters.  I edited for grammar.

Comment: yes
i want to print capital case letters without repeating the word twice

Comment: What result would you expect given "Memi ate Toto and she killed Tata Memi also hate Biso" as an input?

Comment: no , the output should be like 
Mimi
Toto
Tata
Biso

Answer (score 7):

I don't know the C#/.net regex lib at all, but this this regex pattern will do it:

```
\b[A-Z][a-z]+
```

the \b means the match can only start at the beginning of a word. change + to * if you want to allow single-word capitals.

Edit: You want to match "McDonald's"?

```
\b[A-Z][A-Za-z']+
```

If you don't want to match ' if it only appears at the end of a string, then just do this:

```
\b[A-Z][A-Za-z']+(?<!')
```

Comment: Like DavidB pointed out for Rizzle above, it won't match McDonald's correctly, though getting closer.

Comment: for McDonnalds \b[A-Z][A-Za-z]+ would be ok, I think

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure why I'm posting this...

```
   string[] foo = "Mimi loves Toto and Tata hate Mimi so Toto killed Tata".Split(' ');
            HashSet<string> words = new HashSet<string>();
            foreach (string word in foo)
            {
                if (char.IsUpper(word[0]))
                {
                    words.Add(word);
                }
            }

            foreach (string word in words)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(word);
            }
```

Comment: this might be faster, too. regex engine is powerful, but it's bloat loaded.

Answer (score 5):

C# 3

```
        string z = "Mimi loves Toto and Tata hate Mimi so Toto killed Tata";
        var wordsWithCapital = z.Split(' ').Where(word => char.IsUpper(word[0])).Distinct();
        MessageBox.Show( string.Join(", ", wordsWithCapital.ToArray()) );
```

C# 2

```
        Dictionary<string,int> distinctWords = new Dictionary<string,int>();
        string[] wordsWithInitCaps = z.Split(' ');
        foreach (string wordX in wordsWithInitCaps)
            if (char.IsUpper(wordX[0]))
                if (!distinctWords.ContainsKey(wordX))
                    distinctWords[wordX] = 1;
                else
                    ++distinctWords[wordX];                       


        foreach(string k in distinctWords.Keys)
            MessageBox.Show(k + ": " + distinctWords[k].ToString());
```

Comment: This code better demonstrates what I meant to say in my answer :)

Comment: Char.IsUpper()...Who knew?! Not me, but I do now. Excellent.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest do a string.split to seperate the string into words, and then just print words where char.IsUpper(word[0]) is true.

Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417122/how-to-parse-string-for-capitalized-words#417298)

Answer (score 2):

use this regex

**([A-Z][a-z]+)**

explanation:

```
[A-Z]    [a-z]+
  |        |
Single   Multiple(+)
  |        |
  C      apital   -> Capital
```

Try out regex [here](http://demo.1060research.com/ep+name@app_regular_expression_cookbook)

Comment: Actually, it would, sort of.  It would match the Mc and the Donalds.

Answer (score 1):

Solution.  Notice use of built in string splitter.  You could replace the toupper stuff by checking if the first character is between 'A' and 'Z'.  Removing duplicates I leave to you (use a hashset if you want).

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string test = " Mimi loves Toto and Tata hate Mimi so Toto killed Tata";
        foreach (string j in test.Split(' '))
        {
            if (j.Length > 0)
            {
                if (j.ToUpper()[0] == j[0])
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(j);
                }
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey(); //Press any key to continue;
    }
```

Comment: I like this, but it will print duplicates.

Comment: duplicates,duplicates,duplicates

Answer (score 1):

Since others have already posted so much of the answer, I don't feel I'm breaking any homework rules to show this:

```
//set up the string to be searched
string source =
"First The The Quick Red fox jumped oveR A Red Lazy BRown DOg";

//new up a Regex object.
Regex myReg = new Regex(@"(\b[A-Z]\w*)");

//Get the matches, turn then into strings, de-dupe them
IEnumerable<string> results =
    myReg.Matches(source)
    .OfType<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Value)
    .Distinct();

//print out the strings.
foreach (string s in results)
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```

- For learning the Regex type, you should start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx).
- For learning the Linq in-memory query methods, you should start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable_members.aspx).

Comment: Your regex will miss the first word, if it's capitalized.  Instead of "\s" (whitespace) it should be "\b" (word boundary).

Comment: Thanks.  Made the change.  I missed this case because my first word was repeated.  Regex seems to have a lot of special cases.

Answer (score 1):

Appropriate regex: `\b\p{Lu}\p{L}*`

```
var result = 
    Regex.Matches(input, @"\b\p{Lu}\p{L}*")
    .Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string foo = "Mimi loves Toto and Tata hate Mimi so Toto killed Tata";
char[] separators = {' '};
IList<string> capitalizedWords = new List<string>();
string[] words = foo.Split(separators);
foreach (string word in words)
{
    char c = char.Parse(word.Substring(0, 1));

    if (char.IsUpper(c))
    {
        capitalizedWords.Add(word);
    }
}

foreach (string s in capitalizedWords)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Comment: Tried that but it doesn't come out colorized.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: It's helps if you get rid of all those extra html codes: the system handles that for you.

Comment: highlight your code in Visual Studio(or text editor capable of indenting highlighted block), then press tab, then copy it.  then paste here

Answer (score 0):

David B's answer is the best one, he takes into account the word stopper.  One vote up.

To add something to his answer:

```
        Func<string,bool,string> CaptureCaps = (source,caseInsensitive) => string.Join(" ", 
                new Regex(@"\b[A-Z]\w*").Matches(source).OfType<Match>().Select(match => match.Value).Distinct(new KeisInsensitiveComparer(caseInsensitive) ).ToArray() );


        MessageBox.Show(CaptureCaps("First The The  Quick Red fox jumped oveR A Red Lazy BRown DOg", false));
        MessageBox.Show(CaptureCaps("Mimi loves Toto. Tata hate Mimi, so Toto killed TaTa. A bad one!", false));


        MessageBox.Show(CaptureCaps("First The The  Quick Red fox jumped oveR A Red Lazy BRown DOg", true));
        MessageBox.Show(CaptureCaps("Mimi loves Toto. Tata hate Mimi, so Toto killed TaTa. A bad one!", true));


class KeisInsensitiveComparer : IEqualityComparer<string>
{
    public KeisInsensitiveComparer() { }

    bool _caseInsensitive;
    public KeisInsensitiveComparer(bool caseInsensitive) { _caseInsensitive = caseInsensitive; }


    // Products are equal if their names and product numbers are equal.
    public bool Equals(string x, string y)
    {

        // Check whether the compared objects reference the same data.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;

        // Check whether any of the compared objects is null.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
            return false;



        return _caseInsensitive ? x.ToUpper() == y.ToUpper() : x == y;
    }

    // If Equals() returns true for a pair of objects,
    // GetHashCode must return the same value for these objects.

    public int GetHashCode(string s)
    {
        // Check whether the object is null.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(s, null)) return 0;

        // Get the hash code for the Name field if it is not null.
        int hashS = s == null ? 0 : _caseInsensitive ? s.ToUpper().GetHashCode() : s.GetHashCode();

        // Get the hash code for the Code field.
        int hashScode = _caseInsensitive ? s.ToUpper().GetHashCode() : s.GetHashCode();

        // Calculate the hash code for the product.
        return hashS ^ hashScode;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    static Regex _capitalizedWordPattern = new Regex(@"\b[A-Z][a-z]*\b", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Multiline);

    public static IEnumerable<string> GetDistinctOnlyCapitalizedWords(string text)
    {
        return _capitalizedWordPattern.Matches(text).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).Distinct();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function capitalLetters() {
  var textAreaId = "textAreaId";
  var resultsArray = $(textAreaId).value.match( /\b[A-Z][A-Za-z']+/g );
  displayResults(textAreaId, resultsArray);
}
```

Comment: This isn't a JavaScript question.